# How to decode timestamp from digital PKCS7 signature?

Tags: c#, cryptography, timestamp, digital-signature

I have a signature with timestamp.
I am trying to decode the timestamp and decode its properties.

```
 var contentInfo = new ContentInfo(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
            var signedCms = new SignedCms(contentInfo, true);

            signedCms.Decode(Convert.FromBase64String(signature));
            signedCms.CheckSignature(true);


            foreach (var signerInfo in signedCms.SignerInfos)
            {
                foreach (var unsignedAttribute in signerInfo.UnsignedAttributes)
                {

                    if (unsignedAttribute.Oid.Value == "1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.14")
                    {
                        AsnEncodedData asnData = unsignedAttribute.Values[0];

                        byte[] asnBinary = asnData.RawData;
                    }


                }
            }
```

But I dont understand how can I decode asnData.RawData

At least I need to get date and verify that the timstamp is correct(it's signature is valid)

Do you have any ideas or expirience?
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the `CheckSignature` method do what you want already?

Comment: No, It doesnt. CheckSignature only checks signature. Timestap is not involved in this method call

Answer (score 2):

A timestamp is nothing else than a counter-signature (a signature of your authenticated attributes). You would to look into the counter signatures within the `SignerInfo` structure.

`signerInfo.CounterSignerInfos` contains a collection of `SignerInfo` and will be used by **most** Authenticode signatures schemes (may be implementation specific). If your timestamp is based off of RFC-3161, then it may be elsewhere. I have found it as an unauthenticated attribute under the `SignerInfo.UnsignedAttributes` property with OID

> 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.3.3.1

With this OID, you can trivially find the timestamp.

```
foreach (CryptographicAttributeObject cryptoAttribute in primarySigner.UnsignedAttributes)
{
    if (cryptoAttribute.Oid.Value == szOID_RFC3161_TIMESTAMP.Value)
    {
        Pkcs9AttributeObject rfcTimestampObj = new Pkcs9AttributeObject(cryptoAttribute.Values[0]);
        //Decode the attribute
        SignedCms rfcTimestampMessage = new SignedCms();
        rfcTimestampMessage.Decode(rfcTimestampObj.RawData);
        //At this point you are obtained the timestamp message as a SignedCMS object - rfcTimestampMessage.SignerInfos.Count > 1
    }
}
```

Comment: *A timestamp is nothing else than a counter-signature (a signature of your authenticated attributes).* - In case of RFC 3161 time stamps this is nearly true but the message digest signed attribute does not hash the original signature directly but instead a time stamp info structure which in turn hashes the original signature and contains additional time stamp related data.

Comment: The OID 1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.14 used by the OP is for standard time stamps while 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.* is for Microsoft proprietary stuff.